# Difference between System.Drawing.Bitmap and System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

What is the difference between the 2? Some examples would be great!

Comment: via WriteableBitmap you can convert the user controls or any custom controls to an image(You can take a snapshot of an control) while on other end the Bitmap is used to work with images(You can change the original image using this as bitmap provides the pixel data of an images)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `System.Drawing.Bitmap` in Silverlight.

If you are asking for a comparison between this in the .NET framework and `WritableBitmap` in Silverlight then the  differences are huge.  The `WritableBitmap` is a simple representation of a bitmap with very few constructors or means of manipulation.  Most of what you can do with `Bitmap` you would need to implement yourself via the `Pixels` array.

Answer (score 2):

The most powerful aspect of WritableBitmap is the Render() method which allows rendering a UIElement atop the bitmap. This can be used to transform images (scale, etc.) or to render overlays, etc.