# Difference between WriteableBitmap and Bitmap in C#

Tags: c#, bitmap

What's the difference between the a Bitmap and a WriteableBitmap? I want to display a video stream on a C# form, which would be more suitable in terms of efficiency? isn't a normal bitmap also editable using unsafe code?

Comment: WriteableBitmap is for Wpf, Bitmap is used in GDI+/Winforms. Which one do you want? There are also other ways to render video in either technology, aren't you interested in those as well?

Comment: I'm doing it in GDI+ (I think its faster than WPF) and yes of course! I'm interested in finding out the fastest way to draw a video on a screen, I'm trying to draw kinect's video output if that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WriteableBitmap inherits from System.Windows.Media.ImageSource

Bitmap inherits from   System.Drawing.Image

Looks like Bitmap was pre wpf/silverlight where Writeablebitmap is after

Answer (score 0):

You can find a good answer there about what is the real difference between Bitmap and WriteableBitmap:

[Bitmap and WriteableBitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305634/difference-between-system-drawing-bitmap-and-system-windows-media-imaging-writea)

And about streaming video in C# :

[Stream Video C# Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342774/how-can-i-stream-webcam-video-with-c)